# ASP.NET MVC Post model item is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an edit view that I want to only allow certain fields to be edited and updated. My issue, for appearance reasons I want the non editable field to be text only without a textbox around them.

I am displaying the data in the view as `@Model.Customer`. This value I do not want to update and want it displayed just as text.

`@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address)` is an editable field that I want to use to update the data.

When I submit the view back to the controller the `Model.Customer` is now null. `Model.Address` is correct. Is there anyway I can use `@Model.Customer` and keep the `Model.Customer` data when posting to the controller or am I stuck using the `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer)` to make this work correctly?

Controller:

```
public ActionResult CreateExisting(int id)
{
    var LO = db.LOes.Find(id);
    return View(LO);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateExisting(int id, LO lo)
{
    try
    {
        db.Entry(lo).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "LO");
    }
    catch
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Error", new { id = id });
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model Intranet.Models.LO

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreateExisting";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2><u>Customer</u></h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table style="width:800px">
                <tr>
                    <td>@Model.Customer</td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address)
                     </td>
            </table>
        
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
}
```

LO Class:

```
namespace Intranet.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public partial class LO
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Customer { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post LO class pls?

Comment: Sure. I just updated the original post

Comment: Thalnk you and  Get action too, pls

Comment: ok. It's updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add html.hiddenfor

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateExisting", "..your controller", FormMethod.Post)) 
 {
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

@Html.HiddenFor(model=> model.ID);


 <table style="width:800px">
 <tr>
   <td>
         @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Customer)
    </td>
     <td>
           @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address)
      </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

and fix action too

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]  
 public ActionResult CreateExisting(LO lo)
{
 var id=lo.ID;
.....
}
```